# how to create basic sliding panel in android (java/xml)

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a sliding panel in my app, which will slide in on clicking a button.
Please explain in details how do i get a sliding panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use Navigation view from android design support library for slide panel.Here is the link of android design support library blog.

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Comment: Can't figure out from where to start. The link you provided is good but there is no basic things.

Comment: Here is the link it will help you for better understanding. http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html